# divisor is equal to zero in sql need to add some sort of try catch

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that i get errors when data gets loaded to this table and the divisor is zero which is the  b. living_units column. I want to know if I can do some sort of try catch or if its zero to show null instead of failing or something that will help not error out?

```
SELECT a.SERVICE_TYPE_GRP,
      a.HSIA_TYPE,
      a.STAT_DYN_IND,
      a.VIDEO_IND,
      a.VOICE_IND,
      a.CUST_CNT,
      b.LIVING_UNIT_CNT,
      a.DT_MODIFIED,
      a.CUST_CNT / b.LIVING_UNIT_CNT AS ALLRGN_TK_RT_PCT
 FROM (  SELECT lp.SERVICE_TYPE_GRP SERVICE_TYPE_GRP,
                lp.HSIA_TYPE HSIA_TYPE,
                lp.STAT_DYN_IND STAT_DYN_IND,
                lp.VIDEO_IND VIDEO_IND,
                lp.VOICE_IND VOICE_IND,
                lp.DT_MODIFIED DT_MODIFIED,
                SUM (lp.CUST_CNT) CUST_CNT
           FROM RPT_SUBSCR_REGION_DTL lp
       GROUP BY SERVICE_TYPE_GRP,
                HSIA_TYPE,
                STAT_DYN_IND,
                VIDEO_IND,
                VOICE_IND,
                DT_MODIFIED) a,
      (  SELECT DT_MODIFIED, SUM (LIVING_UNIT_CNT) LIVING_UNIT_CNT
           FROM RPT_REGION_CUST_DTL
          WHERE dt_modified = (SELECT dt_modified
                                 FROM ls_dt_modified
                                WHERE NAME = 'RPT_REGION_CUST_DTL')
       GROUP BY DT_MODIFIED) b
WHERE a.DT_MODIFIED = b.DT_MODIFIED;
```

The error i get is ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `case` statement:

```
case
when b.LIVING_UNIT_CNT = 0 -- the divisor
then 0 -- a default value
else a.CUST_CNT / b.LIVING_UNIT_CNT
end
ALLRGN_TK_RT_PCT
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a complex divisor expression and a NULL result is acceptable, there is an alternative that does not require repeating the divisor expression:

```
a.CUST_CNT / nullif(b.LIVING_UNIT_CNT, 0)
```

The NULLIF function returns NULL if the first parameter is equal to the second parameter. In this case it returns NULL if `b.LIVING_UNIT_CNT` is equal to zero. And anything divided by NULL also becomes NULL. It's a bit of a "trick" maybe, but it saves the expression repetition of the CASE statement.